# what is a way to ask in python if a number actually exists and is not masked in python

Tags: python, numpy, masking

I have an numpy array with 13 invalid (logs of zeros) numbers that I have masked and 3 valid numbers:

```
 [[-- -- -- --]
  [-- -- 0.0 0.3010299956639812]
  [-- -- -- 0.0]
  [-- -- -- --]]
```

I want to print out something like

```
  numlist=[]
    for item in array:
      numlist.append(num)

for i in numlist:
   if i is not masked:
       print i
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [MaskedArray.compressed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compressed.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compressed) method to return all the non-masked data:

```
print(arr.compressed())
```

To print one value per line:

```
for val in arr.compressed():
    print(val)
```

---

If you wish to save space (instead of time), you could use `ravel` (as @DSM points out). To iterate over the non-masked entries, you could use IT.izip to loop over the values and the mask at the same time. For example,

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np

arr = np.ma.masked_invalid(np.log(np.random.random((4,4))-0.5))
arr1d = arr.ravel()
for val, mask in IT.izip(arr1d, arr1d.mask):
    if not mask:
        print(val)
```

Comment: Maybe the OP is simply looking for `arr.ravel()`?

Comment: @DSM: The OP wants to skip the masked values.

Comment: @unutbu: which `if item is not masked:` will do.  (Of course iterating over the non-masked items directly is better, but I don't know if by "format I put above" the OP means one value per line, or "using this code pattern"..)

Comment: @DSM: You're right; `ravel()` might be better since it does not require building a new array.